# Lookup a value in Column B or C and return key in Column A

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to write a formula that will look for a value in a column, and return the first cell in the row in which it finds the value. So a little like VLOOKUP, but I don't want to search the the first column.

Here is an example dataset:

| Room | Monday | Tuesday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DWG 1 | S01 | S02 |
| DWG 2 | S02 | S04 |
| DWG 3 | S03 | S06 |
| DWG 4 | S04 | S07 |

Here is what I would like to generate using a formula.
So for the value at B2, I would like it to look up A2 ("S01") in the B column ("Monday") of the top table, and return the value of the cell in the 1st column ("DWG 1").
Ideally it would return nothing or a blank if it doesn't find the exact string in the top table.

| Section | Monday | Tuesday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S01 | DWG 1 |  |
| S02 | DWG 2 | DWG 1 |
| S03 | DWG 3 |  |
| S04 | DWG 4 | DWG 2 |
| S05 |  |  |
| S06 |  | DWG 3 |
| s07 |  | DWG 4 |

Comment: Is the example data shown in your post "filler"? Or does it represent your actual data? I see that you have "S05" in the first column, even though "S05" does not exist in your source data. Does this mean you will be entering the data in the first column manually? Or are you wanting a sequence of S01, S02, S03 literally generated in the first column? If the latter, how far should that series extend (e.g., S10, S50...?). The most efficient and effective way to receive help is to share a link to a sample document with realistic data and results entered where you want them in your real sheet.

Comment: This can be solved with one array formula (no dragging). But I at least need to know the actual source range (sheet name and range) and confirm your setup. The formula should go in a separate sheet that references the first. Again, the easiest way to convey this information is to share a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it), being sure to set the link's Share permission (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Hi Erik, Thanks for your reply. This is an actual data sample. S01 will extend all the way to S24. Each of these represents a class "section." So we have 24 Sections. The DWG 1-4 represents rooms. We will have 15 rooms (so DWG 1-15). No every class section will have class every day, hence many blank spots, like the S05 you pointed out that does not have class on Monday or Tuesday.

Comment: So I have on table that has 15 rows (DWG 1-15) and 5 columns  (Monday-Friday) in which I will input the data.
I have a second table with 24 rows (S01-S24) and 5 columns (Monday-Friday) in which I would like the room assignments to be automatically populated based on the data I input in the first table.
Here is a link tot he spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lYARAWBkM-vxOePCocc7hwf_HjGlBiDxXvZopT_IaCw/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks for taking the time to answer, and I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi Erik, apologies the sharing settings were not correct, but you should have access now.

Comment: Got it. We just met up on the sheet. I'll add my formula solution as its own post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your in-sheet data and layout, and meeting up with you there live, this is the formula I left for you in the newly added sheet "Erik Help":

`=ArrayFormula({"S"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(24,1),"00"),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTER(B1:1,B1:1<>"")&"S"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(24,1),"00"),SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(Sheet1!B1:1,Sheet1!B1:1<>"")&FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!B3:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!B1:1<>"")&"|"&FILTER(Sheet1!$A3:$A,Sheet1!$A3:$A<>"")),"|"),2,FALSE))})`

For the understanding of others, the days of the week (i.e., Monday, Tuesday...) are entered manually as top headers in B1:F1. The header "Section" is entered in A2 with B2:F2 blank. (This is just how the OP wanted it set up.) And the formula is in A3, processing data for A3:F.

The first part of the virtual array just generates the `SEQUENCE` of section names (S01 - S24) in A3:A26.

The next part looks up every element of one array within another array. The first array is a concatenation of every weekday with every section number from Column A. The second array didn't technically need to be as long as it is in the formula, because we already know exactly how many weekdays, classrooms and sections there are. But it is written to accommodate flexibility, perhaps for future use where four or six days are required, with more or fewer sections.

That second array concatenates every weekday with every section from Sheet1 followed by a pipe symbol and the room for each row from Sheet1. That grid is `FLATTEN`ed to one column, and then `SPLIT` to two columns at the pipe symbol.

Found elements, then, return the class name (which was `SPLIT` to Column 2 of the virtual `VLOOKUP` array). If there is no match, `IFERROR` returns null.

The shorter version possible since we know exactly how many days, sections and rooms we have (and which I left in a new sheet called "Erik Help 2") is this:

`=ArrayFormula({"S"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(24,1),"00"),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B1:F1&"S"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(24,1),"00"),SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet1!B1:F1&Sheet1!B3:F17&"|"&Sheet1!A3:A17),"|"),2,FALSE))})`

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for doesn't exist in Sheets as Vlookup match is performed horizontally from left to right. However, a workaround is to rearrange the columns within the function `QUERY` and perform a `Vlookup` to it

Here's an example formula you can use `=iferror((vlookup("S01",QUERY(A2:C, "Select B,A",0),2)),"")`

This will also leave the cell blank if there are no matching results.

Here's an example of what the end result would look like when I the string "S01" is Vlooked up:

[image: Sample Screenshot Here]